# Creating a table in html and javascript but unable to use a Datepicker in the date column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a table in html and javascript but unable to use a Datepicker in the date column when inserting a new row but it works when using in normal html code

Here is the javascript function:-

```
//Script for claendar 
$(function () {
        $('.pickadate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            autoclose: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            orientation: "button"
        });
    });
```

Here is the html code in which the datepicker works:-

```
 <div class='input-group date pickadate'>
       <input type='text'/>
       <span class="input-group-addon">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
 </div>
```

Here is the code for inserting a new row in which the datepicker is not working

```
//Inserting new row
$(document).on('click', '.btn_new_row', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    //create a random id
    var row_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);

    var user_id = <?php echo $user_id; ?>

    //get table rows
    var tbl_row = $(document).find('.tbl_code_with_mark').find('tr');    
    var tbl = '';
    tbl +='<tr row_id="'+row_id+'", user_id="'+user_id+'">';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="pickadate new_row_data date editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="date"></div></td>';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="new_row_data purpose editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="purpose"></div></td>';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="new_row_data category editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="category"></div></td>';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="new_row_data sum editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="sum"></div></td>';

        //--->edit options > start
        tbl +='<td>';            
            tbl +='  <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn_new" row_id="'+row_id+'" > Add Entry</a>   | ';
            tbl +='  <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn_remove_new_entry" row_id="'+row_id+'"> Remove</a> ';
        tbl +='</td>';
        //--->edit options > end    

    tbl +='</tr>';
    tbl_row.first().after(tbl);

    $(document).find('.tbl_code_with_mark').find('tr').first().find('.purpose').focus();
});
```

I've included the class name 'pickadate' in the date cell but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ToYGY0jp9w :  This is the link of the video which I took as the base of my code.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Because, The you are initializing the `datepicker` only once after page loads.

Which means this is the line `$('.pickadate').datepicker({...})` which transforms the default date input to the `datepicker`. You are triggering this on page loads, So it will transform the elements which are exists on page loads. After you add new row, You are not calling `datepicker({..})`, So it will not identify the new element.

**Solution**

```js
// create a function
function initPicker() {
        $('.pickadate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            autoclose: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            orientation: "button"
        });
});

//Inserting new row
$(document).on('click', '.btn_new_row', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    //create a random id
    var row_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);

    /**
     All your code here...
    **/

    $(document).find('.tbl_code_with_mark').find('tr').first().find('.purpose').focus();


    initPicker(); // re-initializing the pickers (after add your row)

});


initPicker(); // trigger on page load (default)
```

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=4ToYGY0jp9w : This is the link of the video which I took as the base of my code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the initiation of datepicker with a function:

```
function initDatePicker(selector) {
    $(selector).datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        autoclose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        orientation: "button"
    });
}
```

and call it after you append the html to DOM sending the datepicker input you want as a parameter.

```
initDatePicker("#my_new_date_picker_id");
```